# pure javascript mvc update h1 based on input

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

I am trying to make a pure js mvc app where I update an h1 with the text of an input field. I got to the point that the the value of the input in the model can be logged nicely but for some reason the h1 is not changing at all.

Could you give me some help that why is that and how to solve it?
my code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var model = new Model();
  var controller = new Controller(model);
  var view = new View(controller);
};

 function Model() {
   this.inputtext = "zzzzz";
   this.heading = this.inputtext;
   console.log('model called');
 };
 
 function Controller(model) {
  var controller = this;
  this.model = model;

  this.handleEvent = function(e) {
    switch (e.type) {
      case "click":
        controller.clickHandler(e.target);
        break;
      case "input":
        controller.keyupHandler(e.target);
        break;
      default:
        console.log(e.target);
    }
  }

  this.getModelHeading = function() {
    console.log("from getmodel: " + controller.model.inputtext + "heading " + controller.model.heading);

    return controller.model.heading;
  }

  this.keyupHandler = function(target) {
    controller.model.inputtext = target.value;
    controller.getModelHeading();
  }

  console.log('controller called');
};

function View(controller) {
  this.controller = controller;
  this.heading = document.getElementById("heading");
  this.heading.innerHTML = controller.getModelHeading();
  this.inputtext = document.getElementById("inputtext");
  this.inputtext.addEventListener('input', controller);
  console.log('view called');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" : content="width=device-width">
  <title>Vanilla MVC Framework</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./Config.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./Model.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./Controller.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./View.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id='inputtext' /></input>
  <h1 id='heading'></h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link the view to the controller, then modify the view from the controller.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var model = new Model();
  var controller = new Controller(model);
  var view = new View(controller);
};

 function Model() {
   this.inputtext = "zzzzz";
   this.heading = this.inputtext;
   console.log('model called');
 };
 
 function Controller(model) {
  var controller = this;
  this.model = model;

  this.handleEvent = function(e) {
    switch (e.type) {
      case "click":
        controller.clickHandler(e.target);
        break;
      case "input":
        controller.keyupHandler(e.target);
        break;
      default:
        console.log(e.target);
    }
  }

  this.getModelHeading = function() {
    // console.log("from getmodel: " + controller.model.inputtext + "heading " + controller.model.heading);
    controller.model.heading = controller.model.inputtext;
    return controller.model.heading;
  }

  this.keyupHandler = function(target) {
    controller.model.inputtext = target.value;
    controller.view.heading.innerHTML=controller.getModelHeading();
  }

  console.log('controller called');
};

function View(controller) {
  this.controller = controller;
  this.heading = document.getElementById("heading");
  this.heading.innerHTML = controller.getModelHeading();
  this.inputtext = document.getElementById("inputtext");
  this.inputtext.addEventListener('input', controller);
  controller.view = this;
  console.log('view called');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" : content="width=device-width">
  <title>Vanilla MVC Framework</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./Config.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./Model.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./Controller.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./View.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id='inputtext' />
  <h1 id='heading'></h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you but then shouldn't it be like that the controller updates the model and then then the view gets updated based on that? not the controller updating the view directly

Comment: Yes you need to design it like that, here the model is bound to controller, but the model should be bound to view, create the model passing a view into it, like `new Model(view)` from inside the controller. The model can now be accessed and modified by controller.

Comment: so then is it not mvc now?

Comment: Your model and view are not connected, this model has no property that points to neither the `input` nor the `h1` elements. So the model cannot read or modify them. The model only holds the value of input, it should hold the `input` element as well. Follow my previous comment.

Comment: hmm it is so confusing

Answer (score 0):

You update the h1 element only in the constructor of View class.
In keyUp event handler you update the only model but you haven't reassigned the view.heading.innerHtml value.

Only your View should know about where in DOM to display a model.property. Therefore, my suggestion to you add this code in your View:

```
function View(controller) {
  var _self = this;

  this.controller = controller;
  this.heading = document.getElementById("heading");
  updateHeading.call(_self);

  this.inputtext = document.getElementById("inputtext");
  this.inputtext.addEventListener('input', function(e){
      controler.handleEvent(e);
      updateHeading.call(_self);
  });
  console.log('view called');

  function updateHeading(){
       this.heading.innerHTML = controller.getModelHeading();
  }
}
```

Comment: hey i added this, but i still get the same result

Comment: I'm sory, that's because the context (this) in updateHeading was not an instance of View.

use this code:

function View(controller) {
var _self = this;
..
updateHeading.call(_self);

  this.inputtext.addEventListener('input', function(e){
      controler.handleEvent(e);
      updateHeading.call(_self);
  });
 
  function updateHeading(){
       this.heading.innerHTML = controller.getModelHeading();
  }
}